# Using Chrome JavaScript Debugger / How to break on page loading events

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

I'm using chrome's debugger and I'm good when it comes to setting break points once a page is running. My problem is when I do either f5 or press enter on the URL line my break points disappear.  How can I set a break point in code that happens when the page first loads?

Comment: breakpoints don't disappear when you reload the page.

Comment: I've tried both f5 and just positioning my cursor on the url and pressing enter.  both cases cause the break point to no longer be in the code (chrome and ff 5.).  Pablo, how do you reload the page so they don't go away?

Comment: In my machine CTRL+R works fine

Comment: Is it possible that the URL that the JavaScript code is accessed at is changing each reload?  Chrome won't have any existing breakpoints to set if it thinks that it hasn't seen the file before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Later versions of Safari and Firefox should work properly with breakpoints across reloads, but one needs to be sure that the query is exactly the same between requests.  ExtJS 4, for instance, adds a `_dc=<epoch>` that will disable the cache.

To stop that behavior, add the following:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    disableCaching: false,
    enabled: true
});
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 140):

- In Chrome Developer Tools, go to the **Sources** tab.
- On the right, open up **Event Listener Breakpoints**, where you can set breakpoints on events.
- Expand the **DOM Mutation** section.
- Check the **DOMContentLoaded** breakpoint.

Then reload the page and you'll end up in the debugger.

Comment: This seems to be out of date, can't find this anymore.

Comment: @Aerovistae it's still there in Chrome 35 for Windows. (I edited the answer because I said "left" when I should have said "right".)

Comment: Option is still present in Chrome 54, but it doesn’t seem to work. I press F5 and the page reloads without the debugger starting.

Comment: Worked fine on Chrome 54.0.2840.99.

Comment: This worked for me after setting a breakpoint on the "Load > load" entry in the _Event Listener Breakpoints_ tab (Chrome 65).

Comment: @nwinkler You can use _Load_ if you like, but _DOMContentLoaded_ fires earlier and so may be more useful.

Comment: I had to use `Script` > `Script First Statement`: a script seemed to trigger a reload before the `DOMContentLoaded` or `Load` > `load` got hit.

Comment: @DonHatch Indeed that is the location my answer specified, but it was not crystal-clear. I have clarified the steps to make it more obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

Try putting `debugger;` in your code. That also works in FF's Firebug

Comment: Good solution if you can easily change the code, bad if you can't.

Comment: Since it's javascript, you can add the `debugger;` statement to any website you're viewing by using the Chrome Developer Tools (Wrench -> Tools -> Developer Tools -> click "sources", find the javascript function.. Obviously not simple if the code is minimized or has lots of functions to dig through. There is a way to view the Event Listeners from this Developer Tools too, but it wasn't obvious to me how to. Hope that helps

Comment: @dolan, unfortunately this doesn't work if you want to break immediately on page load.

Comment: @dolan see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13372025/61754) for debugging on page load.

Answer (score 4):

**Chrome JavaScript debugger**

I use the next approach that is suitable for `Chrome`, `Safari` using `Charles Proxy`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54516008/4770877) and `Rewrite Tool`

```
debugger;
```

or if you need to make a browser console wait

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    debugger; 
    console.log('gets printed only once after timeout');
}, 7000);
```

`setTimeout` is a function that will trigger after delay to give a user time to attach the console

Answer (score 3):

Debugger can be set also by using **XHR/fetch breakpoint**

In **chrome developer** tools -> sources tab, in the right pane you can see **XHR/fetch breakpoint** using that you can set breakpoint.

1. Add breakpoint
2. Enter the string which you want to break on. DevTools pauses when this string is present anywhere in an XHR's request URL.

If breakpoint has to be set for all XHR or fetch, please check the option **Any XHR or fetch**

In **firefox developer**, tools -> debugger tab, adding to the above feature we can set debugger based on request methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to stop the javascript at the time it's first loaded in the browser (and not when the DOMContentLoaded event listener is triggered which happen later) simply click on pause button in chrome debugger and reload your page with F5 keyboard button.
It worked for me.