# How to change response body with Charles?

Tags: charles-proxy

I am using Charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com) to debug my HTTP requests and now I run into an issue where I am receiving json response which I need to edit to see how my app behaves.

I was looking at Rewrite option but can't really figure out how to change it. Ideal would be to load whole response from disk.

Any ideas how to accomplish this? Thank you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The Map Local tool is probably what you're looking for. Access via menu **Tools | Map Local...**. Note, you may need a corresponding rewrite rule (**Tools | Rewrite...**) to ensure the mime type of your response served from disk and the type your application is expecting. But recent versions of Charles may set the type automatically.

Answer (score 38):

Share how to Enable breakpoints, then change response.

1. request the link firstly. then enable breakpoint > in the http request right click > choose Breakpoints
   [image]

   2. Menu Proxy > Breakpoints Settings > double click the request link
   [image]

   3. change the Scheme GET/POST > Query *
   [image]

   4. modify the request, change the tab Edit Request > you can change the URL, Headers, Cookies, etc > then click the Execute
   [image]

   5. edit the response: choose tab Edit Response > change the response > click the Execute
   [image]

   Enjoy it. You make it.

Comment: Is it possible to have charles respond back with a custom JSON evertime until disabled? (As opposed to having breakpoints and updating everytime)

Comment: I think Charges can do it. Just read the response from the json file. But I don't have the experience. Please google.

Comment: for my suite it was necessary to remove "Request' mark at "Edit Breakpoint" because in some cases it returns error even if nothing was changed

Answer (score 26):

**Charles Proxy change response**

As was mentioned Charles Proxy(4.2.8 version) allows you to change response body using different approaches:

1. [Map Local Tool](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/map-local/) <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ option</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> - Use local files to serve remote location
2. [Map Remote Tool](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/map-remote/) <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ option</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> - Modify the request location to map one remote location to another
3. [Rewrite Tool](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/rewrite/) <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>⌥option</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> - Modify requests and responses as they pass through Charles
4. [Breakpoints Tool](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/breakpoints/) <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> - Intercept and edit requests and responses before they are sent and received

Read more [here](https://engineering.nodesagency.com/categories/qa/2017/12/18/How-we-debug-with-Charles)

Answer (score 22):

Enable breakpoints, then change response. You should press continue/send request to send it before tweak response.